Does having compatibles world views solve all social problems?
World view
Definition
I believe that each person have an internal logical schema of the world. It is a logical way of understanding the world and everyone have a different world view because it is based on what we believe is true (what is real) and is shaped by what we see of the world (culture, peoples...). It consists of a collection of cause and effects : if postulate A, then postulate B (or more). Thus there is a relation of causality between A and B : A -> B
Some items are at the base of what our world view is, and everything else is build on top of them, creating a network of these relations that evolve during our lifetime: some relations can be deleted, added.
Because of this hierarchy, some items have more importance/weight in the world view.
Examples

If I launch this coin, I have a 50% chance of winning (in the case of a bet)
If I launch this coin, I have a 70% chance of winning (Here this is mathematically false, and for this example let's not assume some strange event so this 70% chance of winning is also false in reality. But the person THINKS that he has a 70% chance of winning, that is why this 70% is in its world view)
Humans never went to the moon because the elites are lying to us. (This conspiracy theory can be linked with many other relation that goes deeper than this affirmation).

Examples of contradictory world view items (just some illustrative examples) :



The world exists because God created it
The Big Bang happened and created the universe




Apples are bad for health because I read it online (don't remember where)
Apples are good for health because I read it online (don't remember where either)



Question
If we consider this option as a good approximation for how we work, could we build a common world view such that everyone agrees with it ? All relations will have an explanation of why the common world view integrate this and not the others contradictory relations.
(Still don't know how to reunite ALL relations in this common world view: What is the first true basic relation, how to reconciliate multiple world view where the base relations are contradictory, how to get the world view of everyone...  THIS IS A THOUGHT EXERCISE).
But I will at least set a base on how to construct a world view: It must be based on facts because its purpose is to explain how our world really works with all information we have at our disposal. We might have to add some items by guessing that they are right (because we can never be certain of a fact), but if another contradictory item is more certain to be real, then we must replace it and eliminate the old contradictory item and all items that where based on it.
So, if we have a common knowledge base (the best we can get out of everything we have):

Could people agree with it? (Every items are explained, and every options that are not included are also explained in a logical way)
If people agree with that common world view, could they act in such way?

-> So do the right thing according to the common world view
This assumes that the common world view can actually predict what is the best thing to do. Of course the idea is not to restrict people liberties

Example: The best thing to do is not to spend too much time on the computer but I do that anyway


The best thing to do is more about doing an action that avoid to a big and bad outcome: No war, no violence, more effort against climate change


Summarized: Knowing how the world really works could allow humans to be at peace and make the world a better place?


We do have a common world view – common sense for where they overlap. But if everybody shares exactly the same world view, we would be automata. And the 'knowledge base' is imperfect and contradictory. We do not know all the answers to all the questions, and they aren't always the same in all situations anyway. So the idea of a common sense and shared knowledge is simplistic. How would knowledge ever progress, if it is a fixed body?

I did not said it in the question, but I am talking about an exterior system that could tell us what is the common world view, thus you are still free.

Is that ChatGPT ? For now we see through a glass, darkly. Will AI replace the need to elevate enlightened individuals to positions of influence?

"Does having compatibles world views solve all social problems?"  Even in communities that share the same world view there are social problems, so common sense says no.

You ask: "could we build a common world view such that everyone agrees with it?" People don't always agree even when something is obvious, widely agreed on, and in their own best interest. The problem isn't a lack of information, it is a lack of... Brains? Conscientiousness? Experience? Enlightened Self-interest? Maturity? It's a personality problem, not a data problem.

Compatible world views wouldn't solve poverty, disease,  dishonesty, inadequate education, child abuse, or a thousand other social ills. It might reduce some social ills, or might rob us of the tools we need to find better solutions.  And it's unachievable in any case.


Knowing how the world really works could allow humans to be at peace
and make the world a better place ?

I believe, that a lot of issues are indeed because people are stupid and do not understand reality and do not understand each other. Being more rational would help. Also being more emphatic would help: to understand that other people have different needs and emotions and reactions.
This is the part where it gets tricky and where we are leaving the realm of pure reason: Person A (due to maybe some issues in their childhood) might really prefer e.g. a quiet live, down to earth in nature. While another might be the the opposite. Now it is easy to see that if both sides are rational and emphatic they will cooperate (in a prisoners dilemma sense) and both strive to build a world where there is room enough for both sides. (And as this is just an example: for all the many sides of human beings that exists)
So the point here is: subjectivity is backed in: It is not that people just do not "understand" things but that there are different, subjective interests of what they want. Most notably there is the class conflict:
Those currently in power have some interest to keep it. Even if the rich understand it (and often they do) and the poor understand it (often they don't) the conflict is built in and it is not a conflict that comes from the lack of rational understanding of the issue. Now of course the rich do not want to be the "bad guys" and so they develop ideology ("world views") that rationalize what they do. E.g.: that the capitalism benefits all, etc... And so some ideological superstructure is created. And this ideology is spread via the institutions that are dominated by those in power. And those in power in turn are in power because of the dominant ideology. Or as Marx expressed it:
"Die Gedanken der Herrschenden sind die herrschenden Gedanken" (The thoughts (ideology) of those in power are the ruling thoughts)

Knowing how the world really works could allow humans to be at peace
and make the world a better place ?

Yes, but then "Knowing how the world really works" would mean that people are able to deconstruct the ideology that was injected into them since birth and which is expressed in all the institutions around us and codified into the laws and norms and language, etc, etc.. Which is really hard.


The key questions would be what you plan to do with this common standard, and how would you construct it.  This can be phrased in terms of model theory.
If you take the intersection of everyone's models, you run into an issue with a nihilist or solipsist.  The former's model contains no statements (other than perhaps the statement that they can know nothing), while the latter only accepts the existence of themselves.  Two solipsists would result in the same intersection as the nihilist.  So that construction can only end in a model that contains nothing, which is not helpful for world peace.
If you take the union, you run into issues with disagreements.  To pick a particularly hot issue today, if abortion is evil to one person and abortion is not evil to another, then we lose the law of non-contradiction, which is a very popular logical principle from Aristotle's era.  Perhaps that can help with world peace, but I find it so mightily difficult to describe logic without non-contradiction, so it's highly unlikely the masses will be able to understand it well enough to support world peace.
There is another approach, where one takes the product of the models.  The result is not a single true/false value for each predicate, but rather an array of true/false values, one for each person.  This could indeed be consistent.  However, its construction may be too trivial in order to be useful.  In particular, it is almost impossible to boil any value down to a true or a false.
Which brings us to the above XKCD.  Trying to find the best way to fuse multiple people's worldviews is famously difficult, and the result is typically a new worldview that someone can now disagree with.
